# Using EBS CSI Driver on an EKS private cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I am trying to using gp3 storage in an EKS private cluster. The storage class definition file was tested in a public EKS cluster and it worked very well.

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: sc-gp3
provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
parameters:
  type: gp3
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: topology.ebs.csi.aws.com/zone
    values: 
    - ap-southeast-2a
    - ap-southeast-2b
    - ap-southeast-2c
```

When I use StorageClass gp2, all pods can be created successfully. However once I changed the StorageClass to sc-gp3, the pvc would hang with following events.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                Age               From                                                                                      Message
  ----     ------                ----              ----                                                                                      -------
  Normal   WaitForFirstConsumer  24s               persistentvolume-controller                                                               waiting for first consumer to be created before binding
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed    14s               ebs.csi.aws.com_ebs-csi-controller-697b8c7b66-lmhvk_368a005a-438f-4fb2-8062-223782880c6b  failed to provision volume with StorageClass "sc-gp3": rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
  Normal   ExternalProvisioning  8s (x4 over 24s)  persistentvolume-controller                                                               waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "ebs.csi.aws.com" or manually created by system administrator
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed    3s                ebs.csi.aws.com_ebs-csi-controller-697b8c7b66-lmhvk_368a005a-438f-4fb2-8062-223782880c6b  failed to provision volume with StorageClass "sc-gp3": rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not create volume "pvc-de9b7509-285d-4ea4-843b-8e27951b7711": could not create volume in EC2: RequestCanceled: request context canceled
caused by: context deadline exceeded
  Normal  Provisioning  1s (x3 over 24s)  ebs.csi.aws.com_ebs-csi-controller-697b8c7b66-lmhvk_368a005a-438f-4fb2-8062-223782880c6b  External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "app/app-storage"
```

I have already added the endpoints com.amazonaws.ap-southeast-2.ec2, com.amazonaws.ap-southeast-2.sts   and com.amazonaws.ap-southeast-2.ebs. Not sure if I have missed anything.

Not sure if I am missing something? And how can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue. gp2 works just fine on my private cluster but gp3 results in the same error. (And gp3 on public cluster works fine). Were you ever able to find a solution? @LiangChen

Comment: Update: I had to update my version of Kubernetes to 1.23 and gp3 volumes started working fine on the private cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Have installed the CSI Driver or Add-on itself?
and all the required IAM it needs?

I am using private cluster too, it works ok

Ref
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver